# Does 'Watchmen (2009)' have more versions than any other movie?

Tags: watchmen

> Warner released a **186-minute director's cut** of the film, expanded from the **162-minute theatrical cut**, on all formats on July 21, 2009. This was followed by the November 10, 2009, home video release of the **215-minute "Ultimate Cut"**.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmen_(film)#Home_media)

Does 'Watchmen (2009)' have the more versions than any other movies?

Comment: I don't have any source to give an answer, but 3 version does not seems lot for me. I can easily imagine one movie having 5 or more versions. my first check would be the original starwars or blade runner, but i think the real answer might be some obscure old movie.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Alternate_versions_of_films found by googling "movie with most versions".

Comment: I just realised while searching if there already was a 'most version movie' question that would be the best way to save this question, do ' regional version count ? Some movies have different visual jokes regarding of the region (cap America list), other have censorship cuts.

Comment: Three versions seems incredibly low to me. For pretty much any movie you would expect at least theater, TV, and BD/DVD versions. Typically, for the BD/DVD version, there would also be an Extended version, if not for creative reasons then for the simple reason of making die-hard fans pay twice. So, that means without anything "special" going on (such as creative differences between studio and director, digital remasters, anniversary releases, etc.) you would already expect four versions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**

Like dna says in their comment - three versions of a movie isn't all that unusual - especially if the movie is older, or there was some contention in the creation of the movie between the director and the producers. Sometimes, rarely, it's actually intentional (the move *Clue* was released with three endings to different cinemas).

The best examples of contentious productions are *Dune* (1984) and *Blade Runner*. Both of these movies suffered from pretty egregious interference from the studio - to the point that David Lynch actually asked for his name to be removed from the movie, which was released theatrically as an [Alan Smithee](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000647/bio) film. Ridley Scott was eventually able to restore his *Director's Cut* of *Blade Runner*.

I have five "official" versions of Blade Runner in a single Blu-Ray set that was released a few years ago.

It might be hard to pinpoint which movie has the most versions - but *Star Wars: Episode IV: A New Hope* might be the strongest contender. Depending on what you count as a new version, there may be at least six or seven, and possibly more than a dozen official versions of that movie that have been released (and rumours of an unreleased version that Lucas was working on before he sold Lucasfilm to Disney).

Another contender may be Orson Welles' *Confidential Report* - but not all of those were sanctioned by Welles or the studio.

Comment: At least one of the Star Wars prequels had a different version if you saw the "analog" vs the digital version, because Lucas kept tinkering with the movie up till the last minute and the digital version's deadline was a week later than the analog's one. And then after a month or two a rip leaked of the upcoming home movie release, and that one was also different to the movie still playing in theaters.

Comment: Yep, Blade Runner is what leapt to mind. I believe there are at least seven different versions. There’s a famous old article from a magazine (“Video Watchdog” or something like that) detailing the differences, and that’s from the early 90s. More versions have been released since that was written.  But ultimately (unfortunately) Star Wars probably takes the prize simply because Lucas kept fiddling with it.